# The JavaScript language service has been disabled, anyone had experience with this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm facing the following warnings, anyone had experience with this?

```
**The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): These files exceeded the program size threshold: .wwwroot\vendor\x-editable-develop\dist\jquery-editable\js\jquery-editable-poshytip.js.**
```

- Visual Studio 2019 - Community Edition
- ASP MVC Net Core 3.1

Comment: Do you have tsconfig.json file in your project? if yes, try to exclude this path!

Comment: I have check in all folders in my project's folder, and I didn't find it

Comment: So try to add one and in the exclude section add that path. it might works